# Pandas - JSON Expand is not working - API Result to DF

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have the following code to get data from Shopify's `orders.json` to a pandas DataFrame. The code is the following and works well:

```
shopify_orders = pd.DataFrame()

page=1

while True:
            orders_url = (shopify_url+'orders.json?fields=order_number,user_id,created_at,id,name,financial_status,'+
                          'source_name,referring_site,line_items,total-price,'+
                          'shipping_address&page='+str(page)
                          )
            s          = requests.get(orders_url)

            if len(s.text)>13: 
                print('Getting Page Number: {} '.format(page))

                data = json.loads(s.text)
                orders = json_normalize(data, 'orders')

                shopify_orders = shopify_orders.append(orders)

                page += 1   
            else:
                print('Finished at Page: {} '.format(page))
                break
```

The result is a dataframe with 11 columns. Two of these columns: `shipping_address` and `line_items` are nested jsons.

You can see how these are nested here: https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/orders/order

I need to expand the `jsons` in these two columns flat. I have tried various approaches. But I keep getting the same error:

```
TypeError: ('Expected String or Unicode', 'occurred at index 0')
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of creating a list of dictionaries, try creating a list of DataFrames -- which you can then append with `pd.concat()`. Also, check if your version of `requests` lets you access `s.json()`.

Comment: So maybe create an empty list like `dfs = []` before the `while` loop. Then, inside the loop, when your `if` statement is true, you can try `dfs.append(pd.DataFrame(pd.io.json.json_normalize(s.json())))` (or maybe `pd.DataFrame.from_dict()`). You could obviously assign to intermediate variables if you prefer. After the loop, you would call `df = pd.concat(dfs, sort=False)`. Something like that maybe.